# How can I convert BOOLs into bytes in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, networking, nsdata

I have a series of data that can ultimately be represented as `BOOLs`. I want to convert these `BOOLs` into `bytes` so I can put them in an `NSData` object and send them over a network. I know that I can fit 8 `BOOLs` into 1 `byte`. How would I pack this data? Also, once it's received, how would I unpack it back into `BOOLs`? The networking part is being handled through `GameCenter`, so I only need to worry about packing and unpacking the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you can't fit 8 BOOLS into 1 byte as a BOOL != A Boolean (1/0 = 1 bit)
a BOOL is a short and only in 99% of the cases 1/0

that said, if you assume it is only 1/0 bit shift the stuff into a byte!

```
    UInt8 b = 0;


    BOOL bool1 = YES, bool2 = NO, bool3 = YES;
    if(bool1) b = b | 1;
    if(bool2) b = b | 2;
    if(bool3) b = b | 4;

    // insert code here...
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSData dataWithBytes:&b length:1]);

    bool1 = b & 1;
    bool2 = b & 2;
    bool3 = b & 4;

    NSLog(@"%d%d%d", bool1, bool2, bool3);
```

**BUT it isn't worth it :D**

Comment: So to put all eight in one byte, could I do `b = b | x` where `x` is 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, and 128?

Comment: thats what mark does to -- he defines more readable names for it though :) a think that you should do to -- to make the code maintainable :)

Comment: Logically the `BOOL` type has two values, `YES` and `NO`, one of which has multiple representations. You can always get the canonical representations (least significant bit 0 or 1) using `!!<BOOL expr>`. So you can pack 8 `BOOL` values into 1 byte.

Comment: Aeh yeah we established that already. See the different answers on how to do it... :)

Answer (score 3):

First: do you really want or need to pack 8 bools into a byte?  Packing saves bandwidth but adds a lot of complexity and bother; over the years, it's been a potent source of bugs.

If you do want to do this, use masks and logic operators.

```
 #define kMill 1
 #define kDrill 2
 #define kFill  4
 #define kALL   kMill|kDrill|kFill;

 unsigned char TheData;

- (BOOL) isMilled { return (theData&kMill)!=0; }
- (void) setMilled: (BOOL) flag { 
      if (flag) {theData |= kMill;} 
      else {theData = theData & (kAll^kMill;}}
```

C unions have some support for this, but that feature is best avoided.

As a rule, avoid premature optimization.  Represent your data simply, and then look into compressed representations over the wire if and when performance problems arise.

Comment: It really isn't worth it I agree with Mark!

Comment: You really think it's not worth it? I'm compressing the data by a factor of 8. I'm not just sending a couple of BOOLs here, it's a couple of thousand.

Comment: How much bandwidth do you expect your user to have?  Its easy enough to figure this out.  Suppose we have 1mbps on our DSL line, or roughly 2^20 bits per second, and we have 8192 bools.  Compressing the bools to bitfields, we'd need about 1ms.  Uncompressed, we're using 8ms.

Comment: This is going to be a mobile game, and cell service can be spotty.

Comment: Compression is irrelevant, of course, if the user has no internet service.  So let's assume we have 3G in a car, where we only have 384kBits/sec (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3G#Data_rates).  I believe that works out to 20ms vs 160ms.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of your data as a collection of *bits*, and use

- `CFBitVector` and its mutable counterpart `CFMutableBitVector`,

which is a CoreFoundation type to manage collection of bit values, or, on a lower level,

- the [bit-string manipulation macros](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/bit_alloc.3.html).

Both methods offer functions/macros to set individual bits in a large bit vector, and you can access the underlying buffer to wrap the bit vector into a `NSData` object and back.

**Example for `CFBitVector`:**

```
// Create a bit vector and set some bits:
CFIndex numBits = 256;
CFMutableBitVectorRef bitvec = CFBitVectorCreateMutable(NULL, 0);
CFBitVectorSetCount(bitvec, numBits);
CFBitVectorSetBitAtIndex(bitvec, 0, 1);
CFBitVectorSetBitAtIndex(bitvec, 5, 1);
CFBitVectorSetBitAtIndex(bitvec, 255, 1);

// Pack into NSData:
size_t nbytes = (CFBitVectorGetCount(bitvec) + 7)/8;
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:nbytes];
CFBitVectorGetBits(bitvec, CFRangeMake(0, CFBitVectorGetCount(bitvec)), [data mutableBytes]); 

// And back to CFBitVector:
CFBitVectorRef bitvec2 = CFBitVectorCreate(NULL, [data bytes], [data length] * 8);
// Test a value:
BOOL bit5set = CFBitVectorGetBitAtIndex(bitvec2, 5) != 0;
```

**Example for bit-string:**

```
// Create bit-string and set some bits:
int numBits = 1024;
bitstr_t *mybits = bit_alloc(numBits);
bit_nclear(mybits, 0, numBits - 1);
bit_set(mybits, 5);
bit_set(mybits, 17);

// Pack into NSData:
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:mybits length:bitstr_size(numBits)*sizeof(bitstr_t)];

// And back to bit-string:
int bitcount = (int)[data length] * 8;
const bitstr_t *mybits2 = [data bytes];
// Test a value:
BOOL bit5set = bit_test(mybits2, 5) != 0;
```

Comment: You should pass kCFAllocatorDefault for CFBitVectorCreateMutable().

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi: kCFAllocatorDefault  *is* NULL, and the documentation states: *"Pass NULL or kCFAllocatorDefault to use the current default allocator."*. It makes no difference.

Comment: I understand this but I err on the side of defensive programming. While not likely to change in the future, explicitly passing a named constant for the default guards against *possible* future changes to this function's implementation. Given that it's a sound defensive programming tactic and, as you stated, makes no difference at present, what exactly is wrong with the suggestion?